# Foreach looping through multidimensional associative array, value of last subarray is somehow overwritten by previous subarray

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, foreach

I parse a CSV into an associative array. The array outputs as

> Array (
>   [indices 0-24...]
>   [Susie Wagner] => Array ( [Chocolate Peanut Butter Pronuts - 3] => 1 [Smores Protein Bites - 10] => 1 [Vanilla Pumpkin Pronuts - 6] => 0.5 )
>   [Mr. Hirthler] => Array ( [Ground Beef with Brown Rice - Signature] => 3 [Ground Turkey with Mashed Sweet Potatoes - Signature] => 2 [Vegetarian Zucchini Noodle Lasagna - Signature] => 2 )
>   )

as shown by print_r of array built in CSV parsing.

Then I loop over the array

```
print_r($meals);
foreach($meals as $k=>$v){

    echo "checking $k<br>";
        print_r($v);
}
```

For some reason, affecting the last element of $meals only, the array output by the individual print_r is:

> checking Mr. Hirthler
>   Array ( [Chocolate Peanut Butter Pronuts - 3] => 1
>   [Smores Protein Bites - 10] => 1
>   [Vanilla Pumpkin Pronuts - 6] => 0.5 )

Rather than the

> Array ( [Ground Beef with Brown Rice - Signature] => 3
>  [Ground Turkey with Mashed Sweet Potatoes - Signature] => 2
>  [Vegetarian Zucchini Noodle Lasagna - Signature] => 2 )

you would expect for Mr. Hirthler...

I'm at a loss for how to explain/overcome this. It's an existing codebase that I've recently made some changes to, but previously worked without issue. None of my recent changes seem to be likely culprits, although I suppose they must be. Nothing has changed structurally about the data, just the processing I do after this point.

Sorry if my formatting is not great, long-time S/O reader, first-time poster. Happy to provide full code samples if necessary, just seemed like overkill to do in the post body.

Edit: Here is the complete code:

[PHP](https://pastebin.com/zNayaQMb) (as you can see, I had to hardcode Mr. Hirthler's values in within the loop to get the desired result)

[CSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/00896d09c48dd87f4928bc242c6df937/8.11.19%20meals%20-%20Meals.csv)

Comment: This is actually the exact data I would expect. The data you expect would be if you added another `foreach` loop inside of the first. Have you tried this?

Comment: @zbee well, no, because the other 26 indices of $meals are outputting the expected values for print_r($v)...

I use another foreach later to individually access each meal for outputting through HTML, but at this level, I'm just looking to verify the integrity of the data being passed to the HTML template, since, it's not as expected.

Comment: Are you parsing the CSV by reference, by any chance? This exact behaviour is explained in this [warning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: @msg  No. the CSV is parsed prior to this issue's occurrence. Outputting $meals prior to looping over it produces the expected data. The loop in question is completely independent of the parsing

Comment: In the code you linked, you are looping by reference (`$meals as $k => &$v`) but in  your question you loop by value (`$meals as $k => $v`). See [here](https://3v4l.org/2rHGh).

Comment: @msg you're right. After initial posting I changed the code to pass by reference in order to be able to assign the appropriate values, only. Although looking back, it was unnecessary and the result of a long 18 hour day... I don't believe it's relevant to the issue

Comment: I appreciate that in your simplified example, your point is valid, but something else is going on in my code, somehow. I removed the passing by reference ampersand and it still produces the undesired result when Hirthler's values are not hardcoded in manually...

I'm not sure how it could be happening, or how to accurately replicate the entirety of the code online for analysis. I tried using the 3v4l.org to maintain as much of my code as possible, but didn't have any luck trying to get the CSV contents from ShareCSV. Any advice on how to replicate more fully?

Comment: Look again at the link in my first comment, "Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset()". In my simplified example there's a commented `unset` line, uncomment it and the issue is gone. When I created the simplified example I noticed that `$activeCats` isn't defined. Here's a new [3v4l link](https://3v4l.org/Udst1) with all the code (minus the database stuff and hardcoded values) and inlined cvs, and passing by reference the issue is also gone. So I'd say "cannot reproduce". See if you manage to.

Comment: Wow, sorry for being dense.  `$activeCats` is defined from an include which I took out of the code prior to posting (and didn't hardcode in when posting the full code). It's still spitting out the undesired data when passing by reference, however, utilizing the unset did solve the problem. However, I'm still not quite clear on how `unset($v)` prior to the loop start affects the data on the last index? Not quite clear on how the reputation system works on here either, but if you want to post it as an answer rather than a comment I'll select it as correct so you get your points. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact behaviour is documented in the **warning** in the [`foreach` reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the
>   foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset()

So at the end of the previous loop, `$v` is still a reference to the last element on the iteration (it points to the same memory area) and when creating a new loop with `foreach ($meals as $k => $v)`, each item in the array is *copied by value into the existing reference* (the last element of the array) overwriting the previous value.

Everything looks fine while you are iterating the firsts elements on the array, but when it reaches the last element in the iteration the current value of the reference is the last element iterated (the second to last in the array) so it gets copied and the bug manifests itself. That's why prior to the `foreach` you get the expected result until you reach the last element.

Actually, the bug is present as soon as you start the loop: if you were to output the last element in the array alongside the current value, you'd see that they are the same. But this is not something you usually do.

```
foreach ($meals as $k => $v) {      
     print_r($v);
     print_r(array_values($meals)[count($meals) - 1]);
}
```

So long story short: you have to be aware of this when using references and call `unset()` when you are done.